# Imprimir resultado de consulta sql en 2 select distintos con html y php

Tags: php, html

por favor ayuda, el problema es que en tengo 2 etiquetas select las cuales crean las etiquetas option con el resultado de la consulta sql, en el primer select funciona correctamente pero en el segundo select no cargan los resultados, mi codigo:

```
<div id="crea" class="contenidosPestana">
                <form>
                    <div id='formCliente'class="formRegistro">
                        <h1>Registro Clientes</h1>
                        <label>Identificacion:
                            <select id="tipoId">
                                <?php 
                                    $listaIdentificacion="select *from identificaciones;";
                                    $lista= mysqli_query($conexion, $listaIdentificacion);
                                    while($resultadoI= mysqli_fetch_array($lista)){
                                        $ide=$resultadoI[0];
                                        $codSRI=$resultadoI[1];
                                        $des=$resultadoI[2];
                                        echo "<option value='$ide'>$des</option>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>

                        </label>
                        <input id="identificacion" type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="13" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required/><br>
                        <label>Razon Social:</label><br>
                        <input id="razonS" type="text" required/><br>
                        <label>Dirección:</label><br>
                        <input id="direccion" type="text" required/><br>
                        <label>Telefono:</label><br>
                        <input id="telefono" type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="13" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required/><br>
                        <label>Celular:</label><br>
                        <input id="celular" type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="13" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required/><br>
                        <label>Correo:</label><br>
                        <input id="correo" type="email" required/><br><br>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input onclick="guardaCliente()" type="button" value="Guardar Cliente" class="btnRegistro"/>
                    </div>
                </form>


                <div id="modal-cliente" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-contenido">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <span class="modal-header-cierre">&times;</span>
                            <h1 id="modalCodCli"></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div id="receptor" class="modal-body">
                           <div class="formRegistro">
                                <label>Identificacion:
                                    <select id="modalTipoId"> 

        <?php //AQUI ES DONDE YA NO CARGA EL RESULTADO

                                        while($resultado= mysqli_fetch_array($lista)){
                                        $ide=$resultadoI[0];
                                        $codSRI=$resultadoI[1];
                                        $des=$resultadoI[2];
                                        echo "<option value='$ide'>$des</option>";}
                                        ?>
                                    </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input id='btnClienteModificar' onclick="modificarCliente()" type="button" value="Modificar" class="btnRegistro"/>&nbsp;<input onclick="" type="button" value="Eliminar" class="btnRegistro"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario que hagas el query otra vez, puedes resetear el array asi:

```
<div id="crea" class="contenidosPestana">
                <form>
                    <div id='formCliente'class="formRegistro">
                        <h1>Registro Clientes</h1>
                        <label>Identificacion:
                            <select id="tipoId">
                                <?php 
                                    $listaIdentificacion="select *from identificaciones;";
                                    $lista= mysqli_query($conexion, $listaIdentificacion);
                                    while($resultadoI= mysqli_fetch_array($lista)){
                                        $ide=$resultadoI[0];
                                        $codSRI=$resultadoI[1];
                                        $des=$resultadoI[2];
                                        echo "<option value='$ide'>$des</option>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>

                        </label>
                        <input id="identificacion" type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="13" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required/><br>
                        <label>Razon Social:</label><br>
                        <input id="razonS" type="text" required/><br>
                        <label>Dirección:</label><br>
                        <input id="direccion" type="text" required/><br>
                        <label>Telefono:</label><br>
                        <input id="telefono" type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="13" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required/><br>
                        <label>Celular:</label><br>
                        <input id="celular" type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="13" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required/><br>
                        <label>Correo:</label><br>
                        <input id="correo" type="email" required/><br><br>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input onclick="guardaCliente()" type="button" value="Guardar Cliente" class="btnRegistro"/>
                    </div>
                </form>


                <div id="modal-cliente" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-contenido">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <span class="modal-header-cierre">&times;</span>
                            <h1 id="modalCodCli"></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div id="receptor" class="modal-body">
                           <div class="formRegistro">
                                <label>Identificacion:
                                    <select id="modalTipoId"> 

        <?php //AQUI ES DONDE YA NO CARGA EL RESULTADO
                                        mysqli_data_seek($lista, 0);
                                        while($resultadoI= mysqli_fetch_array($lista)){
                                        $ide=$resultadoI[0];
                                        $codSRI=$resultadoI[1];
                                        $des=$resultadoI[2];
                                        echo "<option value='$ide'>$des</option>";}
                                        ?>
                                    </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input id='btnClienteModificar' onclick="modificarCliente()" type="button" value="Modificar" class="btnRegistro"/>&nbsp;<input onclick="" type="button" value="Eliminar" class="btnRegistro"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: gracias por su respuesta, me da error que: mysql_data_seek, esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0  ¿alguna mas actualizada?

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, tienes que usar `msqli_data_seek`

Comment: gracias, ya lo cambié, ahora si me genera las (n) etiquetas option pero vacias, es decir donde debe ir el value='1'  esta value=' ' alguna idea, le estaria muy agradecido

Comment: La variable en el segundo while se llama `$resultado`, pero intentas leer `$resultadoI`.  Ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias, que error tan grave tuve. solucionado

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta si te ayudo

Comment: ya lo hice gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que volver a lanzar la query en el segundo select pues el fetch_array ya ha agotado los registros.

```
<div id="crea" class="contenidosPestana">
            <form>
                <div id='formCliente'class="formRegistro">
                    <h1>Registro Clientes</h1>
                    <label>Identificacion:
                        <select id="tipoId">
                            <?php 
                                $listaIdentificacion="select *from identificaciones;";
                                $lista= mysqli_query($conexion, $listaIdentificacion);
                                while($resultadoI= mysqli_fetch_array($lista)){
                                    $ide=$resultadoI[0];
                                    $codSRI=$resultadoI[1];
                                    $des=$resultadoI[2];
                                    echo "<option value='$ide'>$des</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>

                    </label>
                    <input id="identificacion" type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="13" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required/><br>
                    <label>Razon Social:</label><br>
                    <input id="razonS" type="text" required/><br>
                    <label>Dirección:</label><br>
                    <input id="direccion" type="text" required/><br>
                    <label>Telefono:</label><br>
                    <input id="telefono" type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="13" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required/><br>
                    <label>Celular:</label><br>
                    <input id="celular" type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="13" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required/><br>
                    <label>Correo:</label><br>
                    <input id="correo" type="email" required/><br><br>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input onclick="guardaCliente()" type="button" value="Guardar Cliente" class="btnRegistro"/>
                </div>
            </form>


            <div id="modal-cliente" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-contenido">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <span class="modal-header-cierre">&times;</span>
                        <h1 id="modalCodCli"></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id="receptor" class="modal-body">
                       <div class="formRegistro">
                            <label>Identificacion:
                                <select id="modalTipoId"> 

    <?php 
                                    //Aquí se tiene que volver a hacer la query
                                    $listaIdentificacion="select *from identificaciones;";
                                    $lista= mysqli_query($conexion, $listaIdentificacion);
                                    while($resultado= mysqli_fetch_array($lista)){
                                    $ide=$resultadoI[0];
                                    $codSRI=$resultadoI[1];
                                    $des=$resultadoI[2];
                                    echo "<option value='$ide'>$des</option>";}
                                    ?>
                                </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input id='btnClienteModificar' onclick="modificarCliente()" type="button" value="Modificar" class="btnRegistro"/>&nbsp;<input onclick="" type="button" value="Eliminar" class="btnRegistro"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no me parece correcto volver a realizar la consulta si ya tengo los datos